# Routing, should a request ever match more than 1 route?

Tags: php, api, routes

I am using the code here (https://github.com/gregdel/php-router) as a basis for rebuilding my simple router to be a RESTful API.

Though between lines 49-52 of router.php (see code snippet) the developer uses a loop, implying multiple matches for single request (method and pattern).

My question is, should there ever be more then one match for a method/pattern? My understanding would be that this should never occur.

If so under what circumstances?

```
//Run the matching routes
foreach ($this->_matchingRoutes as $route) {
    $route->run();
}
```

Comment: That seems like an odd decision. I wouldn't base your simple router off a Github project that states "no longer maintained" with nine stars.

Comment: I wonder why you are using this, as the repo is no longer is maintained and is 5 years old.

Comment: [Macaw](https://github.com/noahbuscher/Macaw) is maintained, a mere 150 lines of code, and has a lot fewer instant red flags as the lib you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this function:

```html
private function _findMatchingPattern($routes, $URI) {
    //Reset the matching pattern array
 $this->_matchingRoutes = array();
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
  if ($route->patternMatches($URI))
   array_push($this->_matchingRoutes, $route);
 }
}
```

$routes array may contain several routes, not one.
Then, there can be several matches.

Comment: I understood the code could lead to multiple matches, my question was more logically why would that ever occur, though @ceejayoz and other commentors on my question made valid points I had not considered.

Comment: @OliverGiess that will never happen, in my answer I just explained why $this->_matchingRoutes can contain several elements.